# How to add Badge on hamburger navigation menu icon with BadgeDrawable?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-components-android, badge, android-navigationview

I add `Badge` on a button like [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63037203/8043785).

I want to add `Badge` on `hamburger navigation` menu icon with this way but I don't know how.

I found a few solutions but none use `BadgeDrawable`.

This is my code but the result is not what I want :

**activity_main :**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView_main"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView_main);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this , drawerLayout, toolbar , 0b0, 0);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(MainActivity.this);
                badgeDrawable.setVerticalOffset(25);
                badgeDrawable.setHorizontalOffset(15);
                BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, navigationView, null);
                navigationView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Result :**

[image]

I want like this :

[image]

**My question :** Can I add `Badge` on `hamburger navigation` menu icon with `BadgeDrawable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `DrawerArrowDrawable` class and override the draw(canvas: Canvas) method. For detailed example guide visit this link
https://android.pcsalt.com/add-badge-count-to-navigation-drawer-hamburger-icon-android/

Comment: Thanks. I followed the steps in the link and did it.

Comment: For the record, the solution on that page is the one given on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43881131) that somebody just naively translated into Kotlin.